# Unloading props that have been mapped from state (mapStateToProps) when switching URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So here is the scenario:

- User logs in and they are sent `/home`
- `/home` has a list of projects
- clicking on a project brings the user `/documents/58` where the number is the project
- this URL lists all of the documents associated with the project
- the user navigates back to `/home` with `navbar` and click on another project

The issue I am having is when the user goes to `/documents/58`, then navigates back to `/home`, then clicks on another project (`/documents/61` for example), it still shows the `/documents/58` documents until the server responds with `/documents/58`.

**How do I clear out the current values for props that have been mapped from Redux state (mapStateToProps)?**

I know I need to use `componentWillUnmount()`, just not sure what to put in it. `this.props.planning_meeting = undefined` results in a `read-only` error.

Here is what I have for this container:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class PlanningMeeting extends Component {

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.planning_meeting = undefined;
    }

    renderDocuments() {
        const { planning_meeting } = this.props;

        if (!planning_meeting) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        if (_.isEmpty(this.props.planning_meeting)) {
            return (
                <li>Nothing at this time.</li>
            );
        } else {
            return _.map(this.props.planning_meeting, pm => {
                return (
                    <li key={pm.document}>
                        <Link to={`/documents/${pm.document}`}>{pm.document}</Link>
                    </li>
                );
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className='panel panel-default'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <h4><strong>Planning Meeting</strong></h4>
                </div>

                <div className='panel-body'>
                    <ul className='survey-list'>{this.renderDocuments()}</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        planning_meeting: state.documents.planning_meeting
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlanningMeeting);
```

Comment: In `componentWillUnmount`, you will have to dispatch a redux action which will delete the data from the redux store.

Comment: Geez, that really didn't even occur to me. Going to put a `this.props.clearProps()` in `componentWillUnmount()` that will clear out the store. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments above, you can take it a step further and structure your state so that each project is organized by a unique id (pm.document).

You can then access `planning_meeting[id]` in your component where `id === pm.document` which you can get from the url param. You won't need to bother clearing out the props in this case.

Additional benefit to this approach is that you can ensure the component will have the correct data between route transitions to itself. For instance, if you want users to navigate directly from `/documents/1` to `/documents/2`, react router will not unmount the PlanningMeeting component since it's reused in the new route. In this case, your clear props logic won't work since `componentWillUnmount` will not be called. By storing your projects in state by document id, you can ensure that appropriate data will be populated even when navigating to the new route.

This essentially caches your state, so if you plan on modifying the data in the state, you need to make sure to define redux actions to update the state accordingly.